# Where in a CV should I mention a relevant but unpaid (volunteer) project?

Tags: resume

I'm writing up a CV (my secret identity is a mild-mannered software engineer); there's a volunteer project I did (related to my undergrad studies) that I want to describe, and I'm not sure where to put it.

It's a standalone program which completes a certain task. Is that "work experience" because it's basically similar to working? Possibly "Education" because the work was in the context of my degree? Or something else?

And, seeing as this was a side-project which I worked on for a long period but at low intensity - how should I be describing the timeframe of this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did it for educational credit, put it with Education.

If you did it in a field which happens to be the one in which you got your degree, but your university didn't care one way or the other, put it under Work.

Timeframe is always just dates: September 2008–May 2010.

Comment: Started out as educational credit, but went way way beyond that. I'm not sure where that falls...

Comment: @Standback then I would put it under education, as the initial driver for the project.

Comment: I agree. You wouldn't have taken the job initially if not for the educational credit. You can always explain more in the bullets, cover letter, and/or interview.